# using "Shift+Space" in org-mode capture minibuffer

Tags: org-mode, minibuffer, org-capture, ivy

Using Emacs 28.2 (graphical, not text mode) from https://emacsformacosx.com with `org-mode` 9.5.5 and `ivy`.

When entering a task description in the mini-buffer via org-capture, I occasionally enter both the Shift and the Space keys instead of just Space. Rather than just putting a space character into the task description, this blanks the entry so I have to re-enter the task description from scratch.

Not sure if this is an org-mode setting or plain Emacs, but could anybody point me into the right direction on how to change this behaviour so that Shift+Space yields in a simple Space character in this context?

*EDIT* Capture template is as follows

```
       (global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'org-capture)
       (setq org-capture-templates
         '(("t" "Todo (work)" entry
            (file+olp "~/Workcloud/org/WORK.org" "CAPTURE" "Org-Capture")
            "* TODO %^{Task Description}" :prepend t)
           ("n" "Note (work)" entry
            (file+olp "~/Workcloud/org/WORK.org" "CAPTURE" "Org-Capture")
            (file "~/Workcloud/org/capture-note.txt")
        :prepend t)))
```

*EDIT2*

Inspecting the key bindings in the minibuffer, I found this

> S-SPC runs the command ivy-restrict-to-matches, which is an
> interactive byte-compiled Lisp function in ‘ivy.el’.
>
> It is bound to S-SPC.
>
> (ivy-restrict-to-matches)
>
> Restrict candidates to current input and erase input.

So I think I know where to look next.

Comment: Please add your capture template to your question. Normally, the minibuffer is *NOT* used for entering task descriptions, so it seems you are doing something different: we need to know about that.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for your feedback. I edited the question to add the capture template.

Comment: `(define-key ivy-minibuffer-map (kbd "S-SPC") nil)` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I've been plagued by this for ages. You can and should post and accept your own answer as an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @PhilHudson Happy to see that I'm not the only one ;-) Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that `ivy` had a keybinding for S-SPC in the minibuffer, which I simply did not expect (S-SPC is not a typical combination I would rebind, but maybe that's just me).

The easiest way to discover this is to press C-h k in the minibuffer, then S-SPC, and Emacs will happily tell you about the binding.

So I ended up adding `(define-key ivy-minibuffer-map (kbd "S-SPC") nil)` to init.el, which unbinds this. Of course you could bind the function to a different key combination, but I had no use for it.